# Gradle filter replace tokens in XML file

Tags: gradle

I have following code below to replace token inside in my xml file but the code is not working when I tried to use project variable. I am passing variable test as -Ptest="value". Hard coding the value works, but I can't hard value when building my project.

#### applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="myclass">
        <property name="clientInfo" value="@test@"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

#### build.gradle

```groovy
task replaceTokens(type: Copy) {    
    from "${buildDir}/classes/main/WEB-INF/spring"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [test: "${project.test}"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML you use the token `@test@`, but in your task config you tell Gradle to replace `@APPNAME@`, this does not match, so nothing is replaced. Change either to match the other and it will work.

Besides that, `"${project.test}"` is not really necessary, just writing `project.test` or even `test` will be sufficient. No need to dynamically resolve the variable if it is the only content of the String.

And another besides, it might not be the best idea to make this as a separate copy task, it works against reliable and good working up-to-date checks if you have different tasks that produce output in the same location. For this use-case you have the `processTestResources` task that you can configure, e. g. with a `filesMatching` block where you match your file to be replaced in and then configure the filter in there.

Additionally, no matter whether you use an own task or configure the `processTestResources` task, you should also add the value of your `test` property to the inputs of the task, so that the up-to-date check mechanism knows it has to rerun the task if the property value changes. Otherwise the task is simply skipped as up-to-date even if the value changes.

Comment: That was typo on my part, corrected but it still does not work. When I use just test in token value, I am getting class cast exception. Do you have a sample code to share?

Comment: What is the exact exception you get? The values in the `tokens` map have to be plain `String` objects. If you want to use `"${project.test}"`, this is a `GString` object, so you have to use `"${project.test}" as String`. Using `tokens: [test: test]` here works fine if `test` is a project property. If it is not, `test` instead resolves to the task named `test` and it would result in a `ClassCastException` of course. I think the only way to prevent this is to either make sure the property always is set, or you would have to name your property not like a task name.

Comment: Additionally, no matter whether you use an own task or configure the `processTestResources` task, you should also add the value of your `test` property to the inputs of the task, so that the up-to-date check mechanism knows it has to rerun the task if the property value changes. Otherwise the task is simply skipped as up-to-date even if the value changes.